# Binary classification - computing average of accuracy per class does not equal overall accuracy

Tags: binary, keras, classification, floating-accuracy

I have a binary classification problem with balanced number of examples per class. When testing the performance of the classifier on the test set, if I use all examples from both classes I get an accuracy of 79.87 %. However, when testing on the classes individually, accuracy per class 1 is 73.41 % and accuracy per class 2 is 63.31 %. The problem is that if I compute the average accuracy for the two classes, i.e. (73.41 + 63.31) /2 = 68.36 %, which does not equal 79.87 %.

How is this possible? I am using the model.evaluate function from Keras in order to obtain the accuracy numbers. My code is as follows:

```
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optim,
            metrics=['accuracy'])

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto')
callbacks_list = [earlystop]

X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val = data()
hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=30, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
#get training accuracy
training_accuracy = np.mean(hist.history["acc"])
validation_accuracy = np.mean(hist.history["val_acc"])
print("Training accuracy: %.2f%%" % (training_accuracy * 100))
print("Validation accuracy: %.2f%%" % (validation_accuracy * 100))

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print("Testing loss: %.2f%%" % (scores[0]))
print("Testing accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Why do I get results which don't add up? My setup is very trivial so I am sure there is no bug in my code. Thank you!

Comment: Are they  (exactly) "the same samples" in all cases? // Also, you should be calculating `(acc0*samples0 + acc1*samples1) / (samples0+samples1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find where in your code you're separating the classes to test each one.

But there is a big problem in taking the mean value of the history in `np.mean(hist.history["val_acc"])`.

The history evolves, you start with terrible accuracy and every epoch improves the value. Certainly, the only value that can be compared is the last.